# An idiom meaning "failure is not the end"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

There's a motto in my native language which literally means:

> If the ball is full of air, then when it is hit against the ground, it will go up more.

Is there an idiom with the same meaning and usage in English?

Comment: Any chance of getting the motto itself and some example usage?

Comment: @tanantish: When one's effort ended in failure, we say "be like that ball which [...]" meaning to be content with the failure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*The harder they/you fall, the higher they/you bounce.*

Comment: +1: this is really the only answer which captures the *it will go up more.* part of the original motto.

Answer (score 3):

> If at first you don't succeed, try, try again.

Comment: This is probably the one that's most like an idiom.

Answer (score 2):

***Success consists of going from failure to failure without loss of enthusiasm.***  ~ *Winston Churchill*

***In order to succeed you must fail, so that you know what not to do the next time.***  ~*Anthony J. D'Angelo, The College Blue Book*

Answer (score 2):

**I get knocked down, but I get up again.** *-90s rock band chumbawumba*